# sql query in array()

Tags: php, sql

```
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM themes ORDER BY id DESC";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
            $t_id = $row["id"];
            $t_screen = $row["screen_img"];
            $t_name = $row["name"];
            $t_type = $row["type"];
            $t_cat = $row["category"];
            $t_reg_price = $row["regular_price"];
            $t_sale_link = $row["sale_link"];
            if ($t_type == 'html5'){
                $color_code = "ec6334";
            } elseif ($t_type == 'wp'){
                $color_code = "288aad";
            } elseif ($t_type == 'joomla'){
                $color_code = "f2b600";
            } elseif ($t_type == 'jquery'){
                $color_code = "0f1c2e";
            }

            $theme_array = array (
            array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
            "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
             "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
            "type" => "{$t_type}",
           "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
           "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
             ),

             );
            }
```

This script displays only last result in loop I am trying to display items
when I try array() in while loop it displays error I am new to php so unable to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising and appending array in the loop itself.

While traversing in any loop, new value in iteration overwrites old value.

In your case, array is getting only last value.

You need to initialise the array before while loop.

And append values in array in while loop.

Change

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

To

```
$theme_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

And

```
$theme_array = array (
            array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
            "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
             "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
            "type" => "{$t_type}",
           "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
           "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
             ),
             );
```

To

```
$theme_array[] = array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
            "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
             "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
            "type" => "{$t_type}",
           "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
           "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to built array like below:

```
$theme_array[] = array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
            "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
             "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
            "type" => "{$t_type}",
           "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
           "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Neet to change from

```
        $theme_array = array (
        array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
        "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
         "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
        "type" => "{$t_type}",
       "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
       "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
         ),
```

to

```
        $theme_array[] = array (
        array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
        "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
         "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
        "type" => "{$t_type}",
       "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
       "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
         ),
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$theme_array` as `array` before `while()` loop and use a variable. Try as below :

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM themes ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$theme_array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $i=0;
    $t_id = $row["id"];
    $t_screen = $row["screen_img"];
    $t_name = $row["name"];
    $t_type = $row["type"];
    $t_cat = $row["category"];
    $t_reg_price = $row["regular_price"];
    $t_sale_link = $row["sale_link"];
    if ($t_type == 'html5'){
        $color_code = "ec6334";
    } elseif ($t_type == 'wp'){
        $color_code = "288aad";
    } elseif ($t_type == 'joomla'){
        $color_code = "f2b600";
    } elseif ($t_type == 'jquery'){
        $color_code = "0f1c2e";
    }

    $theme_array[$i] = array (
            array ("id" => "{$t_name}",
            "url" => "../demos/{$t_name}",
            "preview" => "../../projects/themes/{$t_screen}",
            "type" => "{$t_type}",
            "type_color" => "{$color_code}",
            "ddn" => "{$t_sale_link}"
            )
            );
    $i++;
}
?>
```